# Out of Range value adjusted for column 'id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, range, auto-increment

I just uploaded my website on my server and im facing a problem in inserting the data into MySQL table.

I echoed `mysql_error` and I get the following:

> Out of range value adjusted for column 'id' at row 1.

ID is an `auto_increment` value (INT(11)) and my query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,x,x) VALUES ('','$x','$x')
```

I cant figure out what to do. Any ideas ?

Comment: Just don't set it manually, change your query to this: `INSERT INTO table (x,y) VALUES ('$x','$y')`.

Comment: can you tell me value of id that will assign auto to this row and what is the length of id column in db.

Comment: @shubham715 its an AI value, starting from 1, for every product added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set **NULL**. it will take auto increment value for id column.

**Example**

```
INSERT INTO table (id,x,x) VALUES (NULL,'$x','$x');
```

Comment: you can accept answer and also upvote if its helpful for you :) @ubuntu_user

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,x,x) VALUES (NULL,'$x','$x');
```

why column x is repeated here. Use it only once and drop the id column from query like:

```
INSERT INTO table (x,x) VALUES ('$x','$x');
```